# iphone authentication window before navigation template

Tags: iphone, ios4

Is it possible to add an authentication window come up before a Navigation based template loads its first view. If yes can anybody help me how to accompalish that. Also, is it possible to have various views/screens for a navigation based template. Like after selecting option from first screen i go to next and then next and so on. As i am new to this area please pardon if this is a very basic question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Navigation style applications are really easy to do, and work on a "stack" paradigm.  You present new UIViewController "screens" onto the navigation stack, and when you're done with them you "pop" them off (by default you don't have to do anything, a "back" button will be generated for you when you push a new UIViewController on to the navigation stack.

Here's how you push a new controller on to the navigation stack:

```
UserContactInfoVC *vc = [[UserContactInfoVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"UserContactInfoVC" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
[vc release];
```

Edit: presenting an "initial" screen before the navigation screen is sometimes called showing a "splash" screen.   This is also straightforward to do.   It uses a different sort of UIViewController presentation mechanism called "modal presentation."   Any UIViewController can show another UIViewController modally by doing this:

```
PlaceOrderVC *vc = [[PlaceOrderVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"PlaceOrderVC" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:vc animated:YES];
[vc release];
```

I've found the best place to present a splash screen is in the ApplicationDelegate where you're presenting the main window for the application.  I do it like this:

```
- (void) presentSplashScreen
{
    SplashVC *vc = [[SplashVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"SplashVC" bundle:nil];
    vc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    [self.viewController presentModalViewController:vc animated:NO];
    [vc release];

}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    // Add the view controller's view to the window and display.
    [self.window addSubview:viewController.view];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    [self presentSplashScreen];

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain me what the above piece of code will do.. Also, how will i add a username/password authentication window first on the stack and take user to the first view only after he successfully authenticates himself. Thank you so much for your help so far..

Comment: It shows you how to: push views on to a navigation stack, and how to present a splash screen at the start of an application.   Put your username/password authentication in to the splash screen and splash screen view controller.  However, note that Apple rejects apps that require login in order to function.

Comment: Well, yes, you need to define and implement the view controllers in your application.  It looks like you really need the very basics, you might try googling for "first iphone application tutorial"

Answer (score 0):

You could start with a navigation based application and show the authorization view in the "viewDidLoad" or you could make a view based application and create the navigation view programmatically.

In the root Controller (for the navigation based variant):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    login *loginCont = [[login alloc]  init];
    [self presentModalViewController:loginCont animated:YES];
    [loginCont release]; 
}
```

How to create a navigation based view on the fly is in the apple documentation: [link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/NavigationControllers/NavigationControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH103-SW1)

You would do the following after successful authorization:

```
UIViewController *rootController = [[MyRootViewController alloc] init];
UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]
                            initWithRootViewController:rootController];
[rootController release];

UIWindow *window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
[window addSubview:navigationController.view];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Comment: I've had problems with presenting in viewDidLoad -- sometimes it does not work, I think it is a race condition.   Presenting instead in the app delegate for an app initial splash screen is best I think

Comment: Interesting. Probably the most clean solution is to add to the window the splash (or authorization) screen and then remove it again and present the navigation controller (never tried that).